# Can a POJO web service application running in a spring application without Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jsp, spring-mvc

Current Spring application would like to integrate with existing `POJO`web service(javax.jws.WebService) application. WSDL and everything are well packed in a jar file as a dependency. There are two questions:

1. can this spring application calling the API from the jar file to send/receive web service message back and forth without Spring-WS involved?
2. If not, then what is the minimal cost to make the integration?

Answer (score 1):

> can this spring application calling the API from the jar file to
>   send/receive web service message back and forth without Spring-WS
>   involved?

Yes. You said yourself that the jar has the WSDL packed in it. Just because you are using spring in your service doesn't mean that any calling service must also depend on spring. That would be silly.

Use the WSDL contract to generate your calls in your spring service. As far as your service calling another POJO service is concerned, it shouldn't matter what framework the other service uses.

Comment: Thank you. Also do you think the POJO web service requires specific setting to get through spring security, if originally there is none for WS authentication(original spring application has nothing for WS security)?